# API call doesn't render on the screen despite displaying json in the command line (React native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a bit new to react native and I've been self learning for a couple of months now but I've hit a road block that I Just can't seem to surmount.
I'm trying to get my app to display a flatlist of data that is called from my API. The JSON shows on the command line but nothing displays on the client. I'm not sure if the problem is that I'm calling it wrong or something else

````
  state = {
    clubs: [

    ]
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = 'https://api.statorium.com/api/v1/standings/143?apikey=***************'
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log('JSON', json)
        this.setState({ clubs: json })
        return json;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ clubs: [] })

      })
  }
  onChangeText(text) {
    console.log('textChanged', text)
  }

  ItemView(item) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.teamName}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container1}>
        <SafeAreaView >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 10, }}>
            <View>
              <Ionicons name='md-search' size={25} color='black' style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
            </View>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="Search Player"
              onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text)}

            />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.clubs.standings}
          renderItem={item => this.ItemView(item)}
          ListEmptyComponent={() => (
            <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
              Nothing to show
            </Text>
          )
          }
        />



      </View>

    )
  }
}

The API (I'm just trying to get the team name's displayed for now)
```JSON {"gmtUpdated":1662137635,"season":
{"seasonID":143,"leagueID":"24","seasonName":"2022","fullName":"Major League Soccer 
(United States) 2022","stages":false,"groups":[{"groupID":"192","groupName":"Eastern 
Conference","standings":[{"teamID":"467","teamName":"Philadelphia Union","options":"
{\"played_chk\":\"29\",\"winhome_chk\":\"10\",\"winaway_chk\":\"6\",\"drawhome_chk\":\"
5\",\"drawaway_chk\":\"4\",\"losthome_chk\":\"0\",\"lostaway_chk\":\"4\",\"home_win_pts
\":\"10\",\"away_win_pts\":\"6\",\"home_draw_pts\":\"5\",\"away_draw_pts\":\"4\",\"home
_loose_pts\":\"0\",\"away_loose_pts\":\"4\",\"home_bonus\":\"0.00\",\"away_bonus\":\"0.
00\",\"goalscore_chk\":\"61\",\"goalconc_chk\":\"21\",\"home_points\":\"0.00\",\"away_p
oints\":\"0.00\",\"id\":\"467\",\"win_chk\":16,\"draw_chk\":9,\"lost_chk\":4,\"diff_chk
\":\"61 - 21\",\"gd_chk\":40,\"point_chk\":57,\"bonuspts_chk\":0,\"percent_chk\":\"0.707\",\"poin
tshome_chk\":35,\"pointsaway_chk\":22,\"otwin_chk\":0,\"otlost_chk\":0,\"grwin_chk\":12
,\"grlost_chk\":3,\"grwinpr_chk\":\"0.714\"}","ordering":"1","logo":"https:\/\/api.stat
orium.com\/media\/bearleague\/bl15807219791504.png"}
````

Comment: Why `response.text()`? Why not `response.json()`?

Comment: Um I was following a step by step tutorial on recreating what I wanted to do through YouTube so I didn't really question what the person was doing